# DCOS Cluster name change after installing

Tags: bigdata, cluster-computing, mesosphere, dcos

I missed to update the cluster name (cluster_name) in my boot node's genconf/config.yaml before deploying the DC/OS cluster. I was wondering if there's a configuration/properties file in the nodes (or using dcos-cli or in etcd) that I need to change to update the cluster name string (that appears on the DC/OS UI). 
I tried to use the command from Documentation of Mesosphere:

> "dcos cluster rename name new-name"

i don't have any output when executing the command but nothing changes.

Comment: There is no simple or fool-proof way to do this after installation. It can be done, but would be a matter of finding every occurrence in configuration files, changing it and making sure the appropriate services had been restarted to reflect the new name.

The command line rename command only changes how you refer to it locally.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to achieve the renaming of a DC/OS cluster where the information persists through upgrades is to update your `config.yaml` with the correct information. Then "re-install" DC/OS via the [advanced install methods](https://docs.mesosphere.com/1.11/installing/oss/custom/advanced/#install-dcos).

[The DC/OS CLI will not work for this purpose](https://docs.mesosphere.com/1.11/cli/command-reference/dcos-cluster/dcos-cluster-rename/). This command renames the cluster as your DC/OS CLI configuration sees it - the DC/OS cluster itself is not renamed. This is confusing until you look at [this page](https://docs.mesosphere.com/1.11/cli/command-reference/dcos-cluster/) where the text better reflects the purpose of this command.